# laravel eloquent JOIN ON multiple condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, laravel-4

i have a table call **bank**, which store the country bank name, code, etc

i have a table call **site_banks**, which store the bank account, bank holder name and foreign **bank_id** which refer to **bank**

i have a table call **deposit_records**, which store deposit time, deposit receipt, status, etc and foreign **bank_id** which refer to **site_banks**

for **deposit_records**, the status field, value 1 mean successfully

now i want to calculate the total income for each **site_banks**

but i don't want each row **site_banks** call one query to count, this will have a lots of sql query call

so i think i can use the **join**, below is the **site_banks** model file, the **scopeGroupAllSiteBanksByBranch** is where i want to collect all site_banks, join with SUM, return in array

but even i have about 200 **site_banks** rows, a lots of **deposit_records** rows which is ***status = '1'***, but the **scopeGroupAllSiteBanksByBranch** will always return only one row, i don't understand why, i copy the sql query to run in mysql, is same result, only 1 row return.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class SiteBanks extends \LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'site_banks';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = array('bank_id', 'bank_name', 'bank_account', 'bank_holder', 'bank_username', 'bank_password', 'min_deposit', 'max_deposit', 'daily_max_deposit');

    public static $rules = array(
        'bank_id' => 'required|exists:banks,id',
        'bank_name' => 'required|min:1',
        'bank_account' => 'required|min:1|numberonly',
        'bank_holder' => 'required|min:1',
        'bank_username' => 'required|min:1',
        'bank_password' => 'required|min:1',
        'min_deposit' => 'required|fund',
        'max_deposit' => 'required|fund',
        'daily_max_deposit' => 'required|fund',
    );

    public function bank() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Banks', 'bank_id');
    }

    public function transactions() {
        return $this->hasMany('Deposit', 'bank_id', 'id');
    }

    public function transactionsDone() {
        return $this->hasMany('Deposit', 'bank_id', 'id')->where('status', '=', 1);
    }

    public function transactionsBanned() {
        return $this->hasMany('Deposit', 'bank_id', 'id')->where('status', '=', 2);
    }

    public function transactionsPending() {
        return $this->hasMany('Deposit', 'bank_id', 'id')->where('status', '=', 0);
    }

    public function setBankPasswordAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['bank_password'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
    }

    public function getBankPasswordAttribute() {
        return Crypt::decrypt($this->attributes['bank_password']);
    }

    public function scopeGetAvailableBanks($query) {
        $query->where(DB::raw("(current_deposit < daily_max_deposit) OR (current_deposit IS NULL) OR (DATE(last_deposit) != DATE(NOW()) OR last_deposit IS NULL) OR (DATE(last_deposit) = DATE(NOW()) && current_deposit < daily_max_deposit)"));
        $query->groupBy('bank_id')->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
    }

    public function scopeGroupAllSiteBanksByBranch($query) {
        $bank = \SiteBanks::withTrashed()
            ->leftJoin('deposit_records', function($q) {
                $q->on('deposit_records.bank_id', '=', 'site_banks.id');
                $q->where('deposit_records.status', '=', 1, 'and');
            })
            ->select(array('site_banks.*', DB::raw('SUM(`deposit_records`.`deposit_amount`) AS `total_income`')))
            ->get();
//        $bank = \SiteBanks::withTrashed()->get();
        $bank->load('bank');

        $banks = array();
        foreach($bank as $key => $var) {
            $arr = array();

            $arr = $var->toArray();
            $arr['income'] = $var->total_income;
            $banks[$var->bank->bank_name][] = $arr;
        }

        return $banks;
    }

}
```

***SQL Query***

> select `site_banks`.*, SUM(`deposit_records`.`deposit_amount`) AS
>   `total_income` from `site_banks` left join `deposit_records` on
>   `deposit_records`.`bank_id` = `site_banks`.`id` and
>   `deposit_records`.`status` = '1'

***var_dump*** the result from **scopeGroupAllBanksByBranch**

```
array (size=1)
  'BANKNAME' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=20)
          'id' => int 1
          'bank_id' => int 4
          'bank_name' => string 'BANKNAME' (length=6)
          'bank_account' => string '123456789' (length=9)
          'bank_holder' => string 'ACCOUNT HOLDER NAME' (length=11)
          'bank_username' => string 'username' (length=8)
          'bank_password' => string 'hehethisispassword' (length=18)
          'min_deposit' => string '400.00' (length=6)
          'max_deposit' => string '9999.99' (length=7)
          'daily_max_deposit' => string '25500.00' (length=8)
          'last_deposit' => string '2015-02-05 03:04:00' (length=19)
          'current_deposit' => string '0.00' (length=4)
          'created_by' => int 1
          'updated_by' => null
          'created_at' => string '2015-02-04 08:21:16' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2015-02-04 08:21:16' (length=19)
          'deleted_at' => null
          'total_income' => string '1722.00' (length=7)
          'bank' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
          'income' => string '1722.00' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can solved your problem by following the code

**SQL query**

```
LEFT JOIN bookings  
           ON rooms.id = bookings.room_type_id AND (bookings.arrival = ? OR bookings.departure = ? )
```

**Laravel join with multiple condition**

```
 ->join('bookings', function($join) use ($key1, $key2)
{
    $join->on('rooms.id', '=', 'bookings.room_type_id');
    $join->on(function($query) use ($key1, $key2)
            {
             $query->on('bookings.arrival', '=', $key1);
             $query->orOn('departure', '=',$key2);
            });

})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public function scopeGroupAllSiteBanksByBranch($query) {
        $bank = \SiteBanks::withTrashed()
            ->leftJoin('deposit_records', function($q) {
                $q->on('deposit_records.bank_id', '=', 'site_banks.id');
                $q->where('deposit_records.status', '=', 1, 'and');
            })
            ->select(array('site_banks.*', DB::raw('SUM(`deposit_records`.`deposit_amount`) AS `total_income`')))
            ->groupBy('site_banks.id')
            ->get();
```

i found the solutions, with **groupBy('site_banks.id')** then is all set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is The Solution. you can join with multiple conditions.

```
$query = self::select('websites.id','websites.website_url','cron_tracking_details.cron_type');
    $query = $query->leftJoin('cron_tracking_details',function ($join){
        $join->on(function ($queryone){
            $queryone->on('websites.id','=','cron_tracking_details.website_id');
            $queryone->where('cron_tracking_details.cron_type','=',"sitemap_create");
            $queryone->Where('cron_tracking_details.cron_date','<','2020-11-19');
        });
    });
    $query = $query->orderBy('cron_tracking_details.id','desc');
    $query = $query->limit(1);
    return $query = $query->get();
```

This code will prepare Query like this.

```
select `websites`.`id`, `websites`.`website_url`, `cron_tracking_details`.`cron_type` from `websites` left join `cron_tracking_details` on (`websites`.`id` = `cron_tracking_details`.`website_id` and `cron_tracking_details`.`cron_type` = ? and `cron_tracking_details`.`cron_date` < ?) order by `cron_tracking_details`.`id` desc limit 1
```